# Replace String ">=" by "<" don't work

Tags: java, android, string, replace

THIS ISSUE HAS BEEN SOLVED. I REINSTALLED THE ANDROID STUDIO BECAUSE ANOTHER PROBLEMS APPEARED.

---

I'm trying to replace the string ">=" by "<" with the code below and the result did not work.

```
String descricao = ">= 0";
if (descricao.contains(">=") ){

        descricao = descricao.replace(">=","<");
        listaElementosFiltro.get(i).setDescricao(descricao)};
```

The result I get is:

`descricao = "><> 0"` and not `"< 0"` as expected...

Comment: `String.replace()` works reliably. It will not make the replacement you describe. Your problem must be somewhere else, either when you display the result, or you have mixed up the elements in the list, or `setDescricao` does something unexpected. You don't use HTML related to this, do you?

Comment: agree, the problem could be related to the printing part. More details would help

Answer (score 0):

That's strange, i checked it, and the result is what you want, anyway,

- try `clean and build` first, then run it

In case it still not working try one of this:

```
String descricao = ">= 0";
    if (descricao.contains(">=")) {
        descricao = descricao.replace(">=", "<");
        System.out.println(descricao);
        //listaElementosFiltro.get(i).setDescricao(descricao);
    }

    // option 2
    if(descricao.startsWith(">=")){
        descricao= descricao.replace(">=","<");
        System.out.println(descricao);
    }

    // option 3
    if(descricao.indexOf(">=") >= 0){
        descricao= descricao.replace(">=","<");
        System.out.println(descricao);
    }
```

I don't know what `listaElementosFiltro.get(i).setDescricao(descricao);` is, so, i just avoid it.

Answer (score -1):

This is an interesting questions, since it's unexpected that special characters would interfere with replace.

[This](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#htmlEncode(java.lang.String)) would fix the issue (though I didn't test it).

```
String greaterOrEqual = TextUtils.htmlEncode(">=");
String smaller = TextUtils.htmlEncode("<");

String descricao = TextUtils.htmlEncode(">= 0");
if (descricao.contains(greaterOrEqual) ){

        descricao = descricao.replace(greaterOrEqual,smaller);
        listaElementosFiltro.get(i).setDescricao(Html.fromHtml(descricao))};
```

Comment: I doubt that your solution works. Why would converting it to HTML help? FabioFerreiraCS's problem must be in an area he didn't describe in his question.

Comment: @Codo I think it should work, since "<" will be converted to "&lt; " and ">" to "&gt;", and all comparisons will be on strings that do not contain these special characters. I suppose he should try, at least.

Comment: If your code works, then the original code with `String.replace()` would work as well. You have no explanation for the cause of the problem. It's certainly not *special characters* as `String.replace()` doesn't care about them.

Comment: @Codo That's indeed odd. I'm waiting to see if my suggestion worked or not. Simple enough to give it a try to rule out the option if it's not the cause.

Comment: I wonder why the answer got a down vote after 8 months.. I've tried to help